# A hitting time bigger than another hitting time

Tags: measure-theory, stopping-times

My question is :

Show that if $\tau'$ is another hitting time for the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$, then

$$\tau := \inf\{n\geq\tau' : X_n \in B, \mbox{where $B$ is a Borel set}\}$$

is also a hitting time.

Does someone know how to prove this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\{\tau \leq k\} = \{\tau' \leq \tau \leq k\} = \bigcup_{j=0}^k (\{\tau'=j\} \cap \{j \leq \tau \leq k\})$$

and so

$$\{\tau \leq k\} = \bigcup_{j=0}^k  \left( \{\tau'=j\} \cap\bigcup_{i=j}^k \{X_i \in B\}  \right) \in \mathcal{F}_k$$